# Server/client communications not working java

Tags: java, sockets, stream

I am trying to write a program in which the client requests the number of cores the server has. I do this as follows:

**Client:**

```
 public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                Socket clientSocket = new Socket("128.59.65.200", 6789);
                DataOutputStream outToServer = new DataOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());
                BufferedReader inFromServer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
                String numberOfCores = inFromServer.readLine();clientSocket.close();
                System.out.println(numberOfCores);
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    });
```

**Server:**

```
   public static void sendNumberOfCores() {
    Thread coresThread = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                int numberOfCores;
                ServerSocket welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(6789);
                while (true) {
                    Socket connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();
                    DataOutputStream outToClient = new DataOutputStream(connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
                    numberOfCores = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
                    outToClient.write(numberOfCores);
                }

            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

    };
    coresThread.setName("Wait for core request thread");
    coresThread.start();
}
```

However, when I load the server and hit the button on my gui which runs the client code, nothing happens and the button just gets stuck. What is causing this?

Thank you.

Comment: It's because you are running the Socket connection in the UI-thread. You will need to create a new Thread for the Socket(s).

Comment: You have placed the same code for server and client.

Comment: It was an issue with the client/server communicating strings and not ints. I fixed it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It ended up that I was sending an integer when the code on the client was waiting for a string.

Answer (score 0):

```
Server not initialized on the 6789 port and make sure you do that in a separate thread.
Some thing like this.

In Server class:
--Make an inner class say MyServer

    class MyServer implements Runnable{
        final int BACKLOG=10;    //10 is the backlog,if your server wishes to serve  requests.
        final int PORT = 6789;  
        public void run(){
            try {  

                      ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(PORT,BACKLOG);  //10 is the backlog,if your server wishes to serve conncurrent requests.

                while (true) {  
                      Socket ClientConnetion = serverSocket.accept();


            //Now whatever you want to do with ClientConnection socket you can call


                }  
            } catch (Exception e) {  
                e.printStackTrace();  
            }
}


--Start this thread in you main server class

MyServer mys=new MyServer();
        Thread r=new Thread(mys);
        mys.start();
```